# URL for testing my app on facebook

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-iframe

I'm just starting a new app with the php-sdk. I've done an app a few years ago, but this is the first time with the newer setup dialogs.

The canvas url is pointing to my web server and the app's subdirectory.

Right now this is the only code in my app...just the "hello world" from the php-sdk sample.

```
<?php
include 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'myappid',
'secret' => 'mysecret',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

Yes, the appid and secret are the actual numbers.

I've waited several minutes to propagate but when going to https://apps.facebook.com/myappsname it just tosses me a 404 error. Is there another URL I should go to when it's in sandbox?

Comment: Update: using a self-signed ssl cert while app is in sandbox. Would that cause a 404? Or is there just another way to access an app in sanbox?

Comment: Did you define the app namespace in the Dev App?

Comment: @Cat Lee Guess that's it. Can't find namespace examples though. Sometimes it seems like FB development is like a scavenger hunt! I'll start Googling...

Comment: App Namespace is in the Basic Information section on the Dev App. The app namespace defines http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE

Comment: Put in my app name. Working now. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Can you please close this question since it's been resolved? Thanks!

Comment: How do you close if there's no answer?

Comment: I suppose you can submit an answer and then close it?

Comment: Created an answer...says I can't accept it for 2 days.

Comment: Hi Ian and @CatLee In short, you've got 2 options: 1) Answer the question, wait 2 days and accept (The delay is only when new users answer their own questions, to prevent gaming). 2) If you believe the question is of no use to others, delete it. Unfortunately, leaving it open just causes others to come and try to solve it (like I did)

Answer (score 2):

To get https://apps.facebook.com/[APP_NAMESPACE] working, you must specify [APP_NAMESPACE] the App Namespace in the Dev App (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) under Basic settings.

Comment: how do you write a namespace , can i get some examples plz